# Visual Studio 2010 Display message when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, start-page

I was wondering if any one knows of any plugins that can be used in Visual Studio 2010 to set a startup page for a project.

What I want to do is display some important notes regarding the project when its open each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May be you need a look at this Adrian Collier - MSFT's article:

[Creating a Custom Start Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/07/29/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-start-page-part-1.aspx)

Comment: @NiranjanKala Thanks for the edit: still learning to get better texts and references